# Best way to implement asynchrounous call in Angular 8 with user notification

Tags: angular, asynchronous, jakarta-ee, async-await

I want to add an asynchronous call to one method in Angular 8 that download some file

Actually, when i call the method, i download the file (csv) but sometimes, when csv contain a lot of lines, the delay is long and it block the ui.

The goal is :

When i call the method :

1. It must run in asynchronous mode
2. When the file is ready, i must notify the user in the UI
3. The user download the file from the link (attached with the notification)

What is the best way to implement this feature ?

Here is the source code for Angular 8 related to method call and in Backend for the API with Jakarta EE.

**Angular 8 :**

```
private handleExportCSV(): void {
    const target: AssetSearchCriteria = this.assetTargetConfig;

    this.actionTriggerMap.set('EXPORT_CSV', new EventEmitter());
    const trigger = this.actionTriggerMap.get('EXPORT_CSV');
    const dialogRef = this.openDialog('EXPORT_CSV', target, trigger);

    trigger.subscribe((event: MenuActionMessage) => {
      // The call here
      this.assetService.exportAssets(target).then((response: Response) => {
        this.downloadFile(response);
        dialogRef.close();
      });
    });
}
  
// Service
public async exportAssets(target: AssetSearchCriteria): Promise<Response> {
    let targetIds;

    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    const headers = this.httpService.buildHttpHeadersInfos();

    // Build request params

    if (target.filterText) {
        params.set('filter', target.filterText);
      }
    }

    // Build request body
    const payload: ExportRequest = {displayUnits: null};
    payload.displayUnits = targetIds;
    if (target && target.searchWizardCriteria && target.searchWizardActive) {
      payload.searchCriterias = target.searchWizardCriteria;
    }

    const options = new RequestOptions({headers, params});

    const path = new UrlBuilder(
      environment.APP_CONTEXT + api_resources.EXPORT_ASSETS
    ).build();

    return this.httpService
      .post(path, JSON.stringify(payload), options)
      .toPromise();
}
```

**Backend (Jakarta EE):**

```
@POST
@Path("/export")
@Produces(APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
@Authorization(GLOBAL_VIEW)
public Response export(AssetExportModel exportModel, 
            @DefaultValue("") @QueryParam("filter") String filter) throws FrameworkTechnicalException {

        QueryConfig configuration = buildQueryConfig(filter, null);

        List<AssetSearchResultDTO> searchResultList = asset.export(configuration);

        // Build CSV File
        return buildExportResponse(buildAssetsFile(searchResultList));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by checking if you received the result from your http request.
You can either use the async pipe or subscribe in your .ts file. (or .then like you did)

```
var isLoadingResults = true;
this.httpRequest.then((response: response ) {
    this.isLoadingResults = false;
    // do what you have to do

})
```

In your html template, you check if your results have been received and based on the variable isLoadingResults, you display something. Your ui is getting automatically updated, you dont need to inform it.

```
<div *ngIf="isLoadingResults; else resultReceived">
<mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
You see this even when you didnt get the result
</div> 

<ng-template #resultReceived>
The result of your http-request came in!
</ng-template>
```

If I understood you correctly, this is the behaviour you are looking for. If not feel free to comment. 
You can also check out the documentation, they do explain it very well there.

https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/